# Batch file to make folders of selected files in directory of the files

Tags: batch-file, directory

I want to be able to use the "Send to" function (When right clicking a file) with this batch file.

It needs to create a folder, with the name of the file, for each of the selected files, in the same directory as the file itself. (No moving of the file needed)

The following code has helped, but this creates folders for all files in the directory and places it in the directory of the batch file.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b') do (
if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
)
)
popd
```

I believe using the following function will be needed for the directory of the files but not sure about how to call it.

```
%CD%
```

I am rather new to batch files so any extra explanation would be helpful, but not necessary.

Even if it can only run on one file at a time, that will be great since it needs to be no a chosen file basis.

Here goes to learning on the go and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for. Give this script a try in your Send To menu:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:ProcessFile
REM Check if there are any files to process.
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF

REM Process the current file.
SET NewDir="%~dpn1\"

REM Create the directory if it doesn't already exist.
IF NOT EXIST %NewDir% MKDIR %NewDir%

REM Move to the next selected file.
SHIFT /1

REM Recurse.
GOTO ProcessFile

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Works perfectly and much simpler than expected. Thanks!